# Concatenate span results from Python beautifulsoup into string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, beautifulsoup, python-requests

The snippet below works as wanted but as part of improving it, I wanted to join the item results into a string separated by comma. I had been trying but no lock.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = 'https://bscscan.com/tx/0xb9044e77ae66b6f128866e049d55f09b3501de6fc75478e406e4c32d1de4bd6a'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

req = Request(url, headers=headers)
html = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

main_data = soup.select("ul#wrapperContent div.media-body")
for item in main_data:
    all_span = item.find_all("span", class_='mr-1')
    last_span = all_span[-1]
    all_a = item.find_all("a")
    last_a = all_a[-1]
    print("{:>35} | {:18} | https://bscscan.com{}".format(last_span.get_text(strip=True), last_a.get_text(strip=True), last_a['href']))
```

Current Output:

```
                    2 ($598.51) | Wrapped BNB (WBNB) | https://bscscan.com/token/0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c
          13.684565595242991082 | MoMo KEY (KEY)     | https://bscscan.com/token/0x85c128ee1feeb39a59490c720a9c563554b51d33
                              4 | Chi Gastoken...(CHI) | https://bscscan.com/token/0x0000000000004946c0e9f43f4dee607b0ef1fa1c
```

Improvements Needed:

```
                    2 ($598.51) | Wrapped BNB (WBNB) | https://bscscan.com/token/0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c
          13.684565595242991082 | MoMo KEY (KEY)     | https://bscscan.com/token/0x85c128ee1feeb39a59490c720a9c563554b51d33
                              4 | Chi Gastoken...(CHI) | https://bscscan.com/token/0x0000000000004946c0e9f43f4dee607b0ef1fa1c
         -> Wrapped BNB (WBNB) , MoMo KEY (KEY) , Chi Gastoken...(CHI) #-- Concatenated String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the strings that you are trying to concatenate seems to be the text from your links and not spans.

Secondly:
Initialize an empty string (in your case it won't be empty as you want it to start with '->') then add to it the required string on each iteration and you get the final answer.
Try the following:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = 'https://bscscan.com/tx/0xb9044e77ae66b6f128866e049d55f09b3501de6fc75478e406e4c32d1de4bd6a'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

req = Request(url, headers=headers)
html = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

main_data = soup.select("ul#wrapperContent div.media-body")
link_texts = '->'    # initialize a new string
for item in main_data:
    all_span = item.find_all("span", class_='mr-1')
    last_span = all_span[-1]
    all_a = item.find_all("a")
    last_a = all_a[-1]
    print("{:>35} | {:18} | https://bscscan.com{}".format(last_span.get_text(strip=True), last_a.get_text(strip=True), last_a['href']))
    link_texts += last_a.get_text(strip=True) + ","    # add the link text to the string you initialized on each iteration
link_texts = link_texts[:-1]    # slice the string so as to remove the extra comma at the last :):):)
print(link_texts)
```

Here's the output:

```py
  2 ($597.04) | Wrapped BNB (WBNB) | https://bscscan.com/token/0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c
              13.684565595242991082 | MoMo KEY (KEY)     | https://bscscan.com/token/0x85c128ee1feeb39a59490c720a9c563554b51d33
                                  4 | Chi Gastoken...(CHI) | https://bscscan.com/token/0x0000000000004946c0e9f43f4dee607b0ef1fa1c
->Wrapped BNB (WBNB),MoMo KEY (KEY),Chi Gastoken...(CHI)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should store the values in a list (declared before the for loop), and concatenate with ', '.join(list_variable)

Something like

```
temp_list = []
main_data = soup.select("ul#wrapperContent div.media-body")
for item in main_data:
    all_span = item.find_all("span", class_='mr-1')
    last_span = all_span[-1]
    all_a = item.find_all("a")
    last_a = all_a[-1]
    print("{:>35} | {:18} | https://bscscan.com{}".format(last_span.get_text(strip=True), last_a.get_text(strip=True), last_a['href']))
    temp_list.append(last_a.get_text(strip=True))

print(', '.join(temp_list))
```

Comment: I was doing it all wrong. I was creating it inside.